# jQuery: Help with <Select> Form

Tags: jquery

Here's what I have:

```
<select id="barrelSelect">
<option value="barrelDefaultOption">-- Choose --</option>
 <option value="blackBarrel" rel="10">Black Barrel</option>
 <option value="blueBarrel" rel="25">Blue Barrel</option>
 <option value="greenBarrel" rel="30">Green Barrel</option>
</select>
<select id="slideSelect">
<option value="slideDefaultOption">-- Choose --</option>
 <option value="blueSlide" rel="15">Blue Slide</option>
 <option value="blackSlide" rel="45">Black Slide</option>
 <option value="greenSlide" rel="50">Green Slide</option>
</select>
<p>$ <span id="output"></span> </p>

<script>
function onSelectChange(){
var total = 0,
    barrel = $("#barrelSelect").find('option:selected'),
    slide = $("#slideSelect").find('option:selected');

if(value = barrel.attr('rel')){
    total += parseInt(value);
}

if(value = slide.attr('rel')){
    total += parseInt(value);
}

$("#output").html(total);


}

$("#barrelSelect").change(onSelectChange);
$("#slideSelect").change(onSelectChange);
</script>
```

Viewable here: http://jsfiddle.net/A5VEv/1/

I'd like to add functionality to the script so that when a user chooses an option - a default image associated with that option changes.

For Example:

```
 <div id="defaultImage"><img src="default.jpg" /></div>
```

So how can I alter the code so when a user selects "blue barrel", the default image changes to bluebarrel.jpg?

Also, want to give credit to http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/TJcP4/1/ for the original select menu code.

Comment: I don't know if anyone has noticed, but you should really have two equal signs when comparing or else you are just assigning values in your if statements.

Comment: Do you mean that `if(value = barrel.attr('rel')){
    total += parseInt(value);` should have two equal signs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have some way to map the select option values to image names.  if you say that the image names will always be the lower case value of the selected option, and always a jpeg you could easily do:

```
$('#defaultImage img').attr('src', dermal.val().toLowerCase() + '.jpg');
```

You might have to do some other work in order to map your images if they don't fit that pattern.  Good luck.

Comment: Cool that will work.  Can I ask why it must be made into lower case?

Comment: Also, do I just throw this onto the end of the script?

Comment: Only to match your example image name..heh. It doesn't have to be lower case, it just has to match whatever your image naming pattern is (:

Comment: Lower case is largely just to ensure correct filename, but it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @NewToCode - anywhere in your `onSelectChange` function

Comment: All of the answers work.  I gave the answer to Jim since he's a ninja and responded first.  Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to change the image is with a bit of jquery, along the lines of

```
$('#defaultImage img').attr('src', 'newImageLocation.jpg')
```

Comment: As Jim says, in the onSelectChange method, if you name your images to match the value of the select list item.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how the name of the image was going to be obtained but assuming it's going to be the value of `option` followed by `.png`, you might do it as shown in this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/A5VEv/4/**

The jQuery line behind this is simply:

```
$('#defaultImage img').attr('src', barrel.val() + '.png');
```

Also note that you can simplify your code to get the currently selected option to just:

```
barrel = $('#barrelSelect :selected'),
slide = $('#slideSelect :selected');
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works - but when I try to and the code for the 2nd option it breaks and only the 2nd options work.

Comment: $('#defaultImage img').attr('src', slide.val() + '.png');

Comment: @NewToCode Your JS is just fine. I thought you wanted the image to change when the `barrel` select is changed. Perhaps you could update your fiddle with the latest code that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to do is add the code so that the image would with any option select change.

Comment: Ok, so what you're trying to do is set the image in the same div to something selected on the basis of the last option selected? In that case check out http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/A5VEv/5/ - the idea is to make use of `$(this)` to identify which `select` was changed and use it's currently selected value to set the image - is that what you wanted?

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thank you!  Is it possible to choose two answers as "answered"?

Comment: @NewToCode Glad you got it working. And no, you can only select one answer. I do believe that you might be able to change the selected answer. At worst you can still upvote more than one :)

Answer (score 0):

Name your images "optionValue.jpg", and do this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#barrelSelect').change(function(){
    $('#barrelImage').attr('src', 'path/to/' + $(this).val() + '.jpg');
  });
});
```

Where #barrelImg is the img tag for your barrel

Comment: Thanks David.  I was so busy alt+tabbing I missed your answer earlier.